# Ubuntu 14.04.1 installation error Md5 hash mismatch

Tags: 14.04, wubi, md5sum

I have downloaded the ISO file with correct md5sum hash (**119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd**) but while installing with wubi it says md5sum mismatch error as it is comparing the md5sum of the 14.04.1 with 14.04 which has md5sum hash as (**dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153**).
I am installing ubuntu inside windows and it creates a C:\ubuntu\install directory where it has **ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink** file while it should be **ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.metalink**. I tried replacing the metalink file but while installing it again it deletes the existing install directory and creates it again with the incorrect metalink file.
Please tell me how to solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Wubi install is freezing / stalling / hanging on iso download](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520677/ubuntu-wubi-install-is-freezing-stalling-hanging-on-iso-download)

Answer (score 1):

Call `wubi` from the command line with option `--skipmd5check`.  Actually I consider that only a circumvention not a solution, but it worked for me.